# TFS - cannot run multiple releases in parallel

Tags: tfs

I have TFS on premises and i want to run few releases on different machines in parallel. I did not see any option for it in the tfs GUI. Is there an option for doing this?

Comment: Which TFS version do you use?

Comment: Tfs version 2017

Comment: Do you want to run different release pipelines or the same pipelines but different environments?

Comment: different release piplines

Comment: Did you try go to the pipelines and create a relases? what it the issue?

Comment: i can create releases but only one of them can run in parallel, the others are waiting for the first to finish

Comment: Do you use Hosted agents or private agents?

Comment: private agents.

Comment: So what is the problem? if you go each release and press create release you can run all the releases in parallel.

Comment: Nope. It runs only one release in parallel

Comment: Do you choose different agents in each release?

Comment: I created 2 relaese definitions and in their tasks i set different agent (in agent phase) and still the second is waiting for the first to finish